# Multiprocessing in Python - how to stop all subprocesses if a solution to a problem is found, and how to return that solution to the main process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have an algoritm in Python trying to solve a problem.
In this algoritm, I loop over a queue, use the .get() method, and at the end, if a certain condition is met, I add a new element to the queue.
I do this until the queue size = 0 or until I found a solution in the algoritm between .get() and .put().

```
while queue.qsize() > 0:
    new = queue.get()
    if solution:
        break
    if condition == True:
        queue.put(next)
```

My code works fine, but now I want to use multiprocessing.

My question is: how can I, if I find a solution, pass my solution to the main process and stop all subprocesses?

Thanks a lot

Comment: How are you creating these subprocesses?

Comment: You may not have to stop them if you can just empty the queue, or check a done signal when looking at the queue.

Answer (score 2):

Think of this in the context of a client/server paradigm where the client is placing data (messages) on a queue and the server (comprised of multiple subprocesses) is consuming them.

On the server (subprocess) side, checking for an empty queue is a very bad idea because there may be a delay between consumption and publication - i.e., the server may see an empty queue but the client might still want to publish.

What you need is some kind of reserved value that the server will recognise as indicating that no more messages are ever going to be published.

Here's a contrived example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def process(i, q):
    while (message := q.get()) is not None:
        print(i, message)

NPROCS = 4

def main():
    q = Queue()
    processes = []
    for i in range(NPROCS):
        processes.append(Process(target=process, args=(i, q)))
        processes[-1].start()
    for i in range(1, 1001):
        q.put(i)
    for i in range(NPROCS):
        q.put(None)
    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this example we use None as the 'reserved value'

**Note:**

You will need Python 3.8+ in order to run this example